# No puedo hacer que salga en orden numérico y me sale números repetidos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

[image: El código me imprime así :C]

El código no puedo poner en orden numérico con el while y me aparecen números repetidos o me aparecen números del mismo numero, ayuda por favor.
Acá dejo el código:

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def cinco_sentido(num):
  lista = []
  i = 1
  while i  <= num:
     yield i
     i += 1
cinco_sentido(5)

for i in cinco_sentido(5):
  sentido = ("Vista", "Olfato", "Oido", "Gusto", "Tacto")
  for sentidos in sentido:
    print(str(i) + sentidos)
input()
```

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y escribir la salida esperada?

Answer (score 1):

Esto parece ser lo que buscas:

```
sentido = ("Vista", "Olfato", "Oido", "Gusto", "Tacto")
for i in range(5):
    print(str(i+1) + sentido[i])
```

produce:

```
1Vista
2Olfato
3Oido
4Gusto
5Tacto

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Más que nada, sobran cosas. La función `cinco_sentido` es reemplazable con la función `range`.

Dado que `sentido` es constante, puedes sacar la inicialización fuera del `for`.

Comment: Y como haria para que se vea mas separado con el numero, y con un parentesis 1) Vista